# Special PSU for file server; procuring alternatives. t-win PSM-SRA10E-Z-R (ROHS)

Tags: power-supply-unit

I am new here. I am the system administrator for a compute cluster in a Research group in MIT. I am looking for an answer to a specific issue, that is currently causing a downtime for our Cluster. The Distributed file system linked to the server has two hot plug, redundant Power Supply Units, and both of them have failed. The PSU's are made by company called t-win and I can't find anything online about it, except for a few sites in Russian. Any advice on where I can procure the same part, or any other alternatives that I can find in US that would match my requirement would be incredibly helpful. I have left all details I can find about the PSU below:

1) Make: t-win
2) Model Number: PSM-SRA10E-Z-R  (ROHS)
3) AC INPUT: 100-240 V, 43-63 Hz, 15-7A
4) DC OUTPUT: 1010W (MAX)
+12V    83A    -12V   0-0.8A
+5VSB   0-3.5A
SER. NO: T11948794 26E1190089
P/N: B013450001

I have attached a couple of pictures of the PSU along with the post.
[Rear view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X76uF.jpg)
[Specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do7RV.jpg)

Thank You,
Ravi

Comment: Did you try contacting the [manufacturer](http://www.emacs.com/pw/) of the PSU? The product seems to be discontinued, but maybe they can suggest a replacement unit. They seem to be an OEM, so your best bet will maybe be to contact your reseller.

Comment: We tried contacting the reseller, who is taking time to contact the OEM and get back to us. We are out of warranty at the moment, so I am trying to find something on my own. Thanks for the link. I will check it out.

Comment: As you are currently DOWN, and considering that you have zero chanches to reuse your failed PSU, have you considered the option to land one of your failed PSU to a local engineer , asking him to (quickly) check for internal  failed components? I bet that failure reasons have been power/temperature/mechanics related and, as such, not hard to identify and fix (as a temporary measure, while searching for new ones).

Answer (score 1):

Typically you go to the company that made the server and ask for a power supply.  If they are white box servers, then the company that made the enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

From my research you may want to check out the following Link
[Eave Drop has one in stock](http://www.eavedrop.com/power-supplies/aic-psm-2ra1hzp-t1w2-a1-2u-1010w-psu-module-for-t1w-3a10v/)

You may want to do your searches using t1w-3a10v as a products number or 2ra1hzp, as both of these netted me better results for the product.

Comment: I wouldn't be to sure you picked the correct one here. The PSU in the picture does look like a 1U on for me - while the one in your link is a 2U. Also the product numbers don't seem to be 100% the same (PSM-2RA1HZP vs. PSM-SRA10E-Z-R).

Comment: This doesn't seem similar to the one that is in use. The product has a specific form factor (L-shaped) which is essential to make it work.